# Style for element ul

Tags: javascript, html-lists

```
<ul class="gallery"></ul>
```

and

```
     const images = [
  {
    url:  ,
    alt:  ,
  },

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0009";
const imageGalleryItem = document.querySelector("ul >li");
imageGalleryItem.forEach(element => {'ul.style.listStyleType = none;'})
```

There is the problem: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach').
Hello, can You help how to fix it?

Comment: The two main problems I see are: (1) `ul >li` doesn't match any element in the markup, so `querySelector` won't return anything.  (2) `querySelector` returns a single element and you're expecting it to return a list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `imageGalleryItem` is null because selector expression is incorrect. If you want to select all `ul` elements that are direct children of `li` element, then you should use `document.querySelectorAll("li > ul")`.

Here is how to fix it (assuming you select all `ul` elements, not only children of `li`):

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0009";
const imageGalleryItem = document.querySelectorAll("ul");

imageGalleryItem.forEach(element => {element.style.listStyleType = "none";})
```

Comment: there is no changes,